# Mosaicking cloud removed Sentinel2 imagery using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, resampling, cloudmasking

After struggling the cloud removing part of GEE, I have some questions regarding the mosaicking the result instead of using median().

What I learn about the difference between mosaic and median()/max()..any reduced functions on GEE is that, mosaic() can retain all the bands information but the median() is not. However, it is needed for me to mosaic the cloud mask result because I need to resample every bands to 10m. The result from the median() is not what I want, and if I change the function from the median() to mosaic(), then the cloud mask map appealed to have more errors.

Therefore, I'm curious if there's any possibility that I can:

1. Remove the clouds from sentinel2
2. Mosaic the result imagery
3. Resample bands to 10m(B5 band and B8Aband especially)

This is my code, which includes the result from cloud-free image and the attempt to resample in terms of the "median()" result.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/cde371ffe4691b5bda32898a5baf722e

The code in the link above is displayed here:

```js
var largearea = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/ee-ikea2023swedenagb/assets/largearea"),
    imageVisParam = {"opacity":1,"bands":["B4","B3","B2"],"max":8000,"gamma":2};

var s2large2016 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
  .filterDate('2016-05-01','2016-08-31')
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 2)) 
  .filterBounds(largearea)
  .select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B7', 'B8', 'B8A'])
  .mosaic()
  .clip(largearea);

Map.addLayer(s2large2016, imageVisParam, '2016clouds')
Map.centerObject(s2large2016,10)

function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60')

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0).and(
             qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0))

  // Return the masked and scaled data, without the QA bands.
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
      .select("B.*")
      .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"])
}

// Map the function over one year of data and take the median.
// Load Sentinel-2 TOA reflectance data.
var s2large2016c = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
    .filterDate('2016-01-01', '2016-12-31')
    // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
    .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
    .map(maskS2clouds)
    .filterBounds(largearea)
    .select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B7', 'B8', 'B8A'])
    .median()
    .clip(largearea)

Map.addLayer(s2large2016c, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 0.3}, '2016nocloud');

//resample b5 and b8a to 10m
// Finding resolution of a band / image
var b5 = s2large2016c.select('B5');
var resolution = b5.projection().nominalScale();
print(resolution,'B5 Resolution');

var b8a = s2large2016c.select('B8A');
var resolution = b8a.projection().nominalScale();
print(resolution,'B8A Resolution');


// Resampling B5 to 10m/Pixel
var b5R = b5.resample('bilinear')
                  .reproject({
                    crs: b5.projection(),
                    scale:10
                  });

var resolution = b5R.projection().nominalScale();
print(resolution,'B5 Resampled Resolution'); 


// Resampling B8a to 10m/Pixel
var b8aR = b8a.resample('bilinear')
                  .reproject({
                    crs: b8a.projection(),
                    scale:10
                  });

var resolution = b8aR.projection().nominalScale();
print(resolution,'B5 Resampled Resolution'); 

//calculate vegetation index
```

Comment: what do you mean by "mosaic() can retain all the bands information but the median() is not"? what band information is the median losing specifically? Also note that in your code, you are applying different filters to the `s2large2016` and `s2large2016c`, so we cannot compare them directly. Also, make sure to share the asset that you import into your code so that it is reproducible. Currently, it is not accessible.

Comment: Hi Oliver, 
I mean, median() is a function of compositing the imagecollection into one single image, which means it can not be resampled? I am also not 100% sure about this. Because once I print the resolution of B5 and B8A, they are 111319.49079327357, which is not 20m as I expected it would be.  I think the only difference between "s2large2016" and "s2large2016c" is that I apply mosaic() at first and median(), cloudmask function for the second one. Should I replace the mosaic() with median()?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=projects/ee-ikea2023swedenagb/assets/largearea

Answer (score 1):

In the first part of your code, you are doing:

```js
var s2large2016 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
  .filterDate('2016-05-01','2016-08-31')
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 2)) 
  .filterBounds(largearea)
  .select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B7', 'B8', 'B8A'])
  .mosaic()
  .clip(largearea);
```

You are attempting to query images for 2016 from the old [Sentinel 2 level 2](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S2_SR) product, which has data available from 2017 onwards (and later for some regions), therefore this image collection will be empty and this mosaic operation returns an empty image (0 bands).

> Since the image is empty, when you do `Map.centerObject(s2large2016,10)`, the map takes you to [Null Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Island).

> Consider using instead the [S2_SR_HARMONIZED](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S2_SR_HARMONIZED), although the dates availability is the same.

In the second part of your code, you are using a different product (S2 instead of S2_SR), a different date range, a different cloud percentage filter (20% instead of 2%), and mapping the cloud removal function:

```js
var s2large2016c = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
    .filterDate('2016-01-01', '2016-12-31')
    // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
    .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
    .map(maskS2clouds)
    .filterBounds(largearea)
    .select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B7', 'B8', 'B8A'])
    .median()
    .clip(largearea)
```

So we cannot compare any results from `s2large2016` and `s2large2016c` directly.

Note that using either `.mosaic()` or `median()` will give you an ee.Image with the default projection (EPSG:4326), which has a nominal scale of 1 degree (~111km). You can [read more about this here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/projections#the-default-projection).

The difference between `.mosaic()` and `.median()` is that `.mosaic()` takes valid pixels from the last (N) image first. Any pixels that are masked in the last image, it will look for them in the (N-1) image and get their values if they are not masked. Any pixels that are still masked, it will look for them in the N-2 image, and so on. This is explained here: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/ic_composite_mosaic

Median (or any other reducer, such as max, min, etc..) makes the corresponding operation on a per-pixel basis. That is, for pixel "X" it will take all valid  values for "X" from the N images, and give you the median.

When you want to resample an image (e.g. B5 to 10m), you can do this, regardless of whether you used `.median()` or `.mosaic()` to your image collection. However, as explained in the [Projections guide](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/projections), this only gets computed on a "pull" basis, i.e. when you either add the layer to the map, make an Export task, or print some information to the console.

Here's a minimal example using both `.mosaic()` and `.median()` to the same image collection, printing the original nominalScale for B5 (20m), printing the nominalScale that you get after doing the reduction (111km; because of the default projection) and then using `.reproject()` and getting printing the resulting nominalScale (10m).

Minimal code example:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/5cc97402d9db31a269f8023329a1b14f

Note that there are two different ways of reprojecting -- by just using `.reproject()` you are using neighbor resampling. If you want to use another method for resampling, you need to use `reduceResolution()`. Read more about it here https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/resample.

Comment: Hi Oliver, 
Thank you for giving me this comprehensive explanation! I finally understand that I'm using different S2 products, and actually the difference between mosaic() and median(). They're just taking the pixel values in different ways. It is really helpful that you solve every piece of my question at once.  I have tried to fix my mistakes and combined with your code, but there is accidently an error in the second part
 
https://code.earthengine.google.com/42943c15f9ab35bc2859922ad48cb735
and I think the study area from the asset is accessible now :)

Comment: and according to your example, does it mean it's not necessary to use the resample function? Besides, if I would like to calculate the vegetation index, should I also reproject every band to the CRS I want? Thank you:))